# Why does UIImageView.image need to be set using a DispatchQueue.main.async even on the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Trying to set an image on a button when tapped. Verified that the targetAction handler is always invoked on the main thread.

This doesn't work

```
@objc func buttonTapped() {
     self.mybutton.imageView?.image = MyObjcClass.getImageNamed("DarkVersion")
}
```

But this works:

```
@objc func buttonTapped() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // Does not work without this dispatch
        self.mybutton.imageView?.image = MyObjcClass.getImageNamed("DarkVersion")
    }
}
```

On the debugger I can see that both are on the main thread

Comment: To clarify, the objcClass  getImageNamed function loads the image from the main bundle

Answer (score 6):

Correct way to set an image to a button is using of `setImage(_ image: UIImage?,for state: UIControl.State)` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage).
When you use direct access to set image, the button does not know about it and change the set image in state changing routine.
Really you do not need to change image in buton's action method, you just need 
set images for [states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/state) and to change a state of the button in this method. Button'll pick appropriate image [for state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/state).

Answer (score 0):

The correct code from the view controller should be:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonTapped))
        myButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        self.myButton.setImage( MyObjcClass().getImageNamed("DarkVersion"), for: .normal)

    }
}
```

Which works without fail, the difference is that `setImage` is used to set the image.

Comment: Why do you use so difficult way, if UIButton has state property?